# How to access SPUserSolution properties from SPListItem

Tags: development

In my solution catalog I have many sandboxed solution uploaded,
I need to access the activated sandboxed solution in the Solution catalog.

Am accessing Solution catalog under a site as below

```
m_spSite.OpenWeb().Lists["Solution Gallery"];
```

I can then iterate through the list but problem is am not able to cast SPListItem to SPUserSolution hence i could not access the status of the solution.

How can I get the activated solution and its properties

Regards,
Jeez

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, when using OpenWeb(), make sure you properly dispose of the resulting SPWeb object, or you may leak memory.

Secondly; the list items returned by `Lists["Solution Gallery"]` aren't the same as the `SPUserSolution` objects used to get them; you will need to load the `SPUserSolution` using the `SPSite.Solutions` property (which returns a `SPUserSolutionCollection`); and then using the index accessor to pull the required solution by `Guid`.